# Timer is not working on appstart, how can start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, service, timer

There is a timer on AppStart but this time is not working. Also the timer must start at 08:00 every day.

```
 if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 8)
            {
                rTimer = new Timer(rDelegate, null, Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.Today.AddHours(8) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds), Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            else
            {
                rTimer = new Timer(rDelegate, null, Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(8) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds), Timeout.Infinite);
            }
```

rDelegate is below;

```
public static void rDelegate(object state)
    {
        var guidRef = Infrastructure.Tools.CreateReferanceNo("NightMailSmsProcess");
        var traceFacade = new Trace(guidRef, "-", Enums.Channel.SYS);

        try
        {
            traceFacade.AddTrace(new DummyTrace_ { TraceRow = "NightMailSmsProcess :", TraceRowValue = "Start", TraceTime = DateTime.Now });

            var systemInfrastructureFacade = new Facade.InfrastructureFacade.SystemInfrastructure(guidRef, "666", Enums.Channel.SYS);
            var automaticManagementofOperationList = systemInfrastructureFacade.GetSystemAutomaticManagementofOperation(new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "NightMailSmsAutoService" });

            if (automaticManagementofOperationList?.Result?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MetotName == "NightMailSmsAutoService")?.OperationStatus ?? false)
            {
                var vFacade = new Communication(guidRef, "666", Enums.Channel.SYS);
                vFacade .SendNightSms();

                var mediumSMTPFacade = new MediumSMTP(guidRef, "666");
                mediumSMTPFacade.SendNightMail();
            }

            traceFacade.AddTrace(new DummyTrace_ { TraceRow = "NightMailSmsProcess :", TraceRowValue = "End", TraceTime = DateTime.Now });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            traceFacade.AddTrace(new DummyTrace_
            {
                TraceRow = "NightMailSmsProcess ex :",
                TraceRowValue = ex.Message,
                TraceTime = DateTime.Now
            });
        }

        rTimer.Change(Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(8) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds), Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

This method is never work because firstly it have to add trace but it haven't.

Comment: Not sure I'd devolve responsibility of this to a webserver, but if I did I'd probably use something like HangFire. How about windows task scheduler or if you're hosting in somewhere like Azure, a scheduled job that calls a controller action on your site, or a web job (a console exe that runs on the web server, controlled by azure)

Comment: Yes, you're right. but there are many timer like that. My colleagues wrote in the past, I mean I can't change, it have to work on appstart :) other timers working, just one is not working. But I will check to hangfire. Thank you!